# How to create android application with server database connectivity

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I am very new to android. I want to create an android application which can connect with my localhost database and I do not know what to use and How to create Database and pass request to database. please Help me.

Thank you All of you. This is very helpfull. I want to know how to use .net web service and  How can i use json for all sending and receiving work. Please Help me and thank you very much....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you start posting question, please do read the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Especially, the [How Do I Ask Questions Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) segment. Your question should have specifics of _what you have tried_ and what doesn't work in that.

Comment: check this link for Android and Server Connectivity <http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/>

Comment: Thank you now i know how to ask...

Comment: @Shyildo 502 Bad Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Use **SQL server** to manage the data on your desktop and create a **web-service in .Net** on Visual Studio.

*(Note that  it really does not matter what is the database you are using in your server end, because eventually the data is going to come to the Android application from the server in form of either xml or json in the web-service., regardless of what database you are using. So it is totally your wish which database you want to use.)*

Then connect to the **web-service** in your application and set/get data from the remote/localhost Database, using **SOAP**.

[Link](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx) on how to make a web-service in .NET (does not include the implementation in Android).

Links on how to connect your service with Android : [this](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap) and [this](http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

For you'r localhost use wamp server. Which include php,mysql. Try to create a data base by using mysql an dconnetct with php. If you want to inser any data from Android app you can do it by only php(this case). So communicating with android app you have to learn JSON parsing or XML parsing. and your localhost ip address is 127.0.0.1 but this will not support in android emulator. so you have to use 10.0.2.2 insted for 127.0.01.